# How to host an ASP.NET MVC website as sub-directory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC website that I would like to place in a sub-directory of an existing web domain. This way the URL would be something along the lines of `www.existingsite.com/newsite/login` rather than `www.newsite.com/login`.

I've tried adding it to the `RouteConfig.cs` file like what's below but that didn't work at all.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "NewSite/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
}
```

After that I went into the properties of the project and set the virtual directory to be `localhost:port/NewSite`. That seemed to work until I attempt to decrypt a cookie with the user's information.

The decryption throws an error

> Error occurred during a cryptographic operation.

It blows up on this specific line:

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie.Value);
```

Is it possible to host an ASP.NET MVC website in a sub-directory or does it have to be at the root level?

Comment: Does the cookie you're trying to decrypt has been created by existingsite ? If that's the case both sites need to use the same machine key is their web.config

Comment: The cookie is created by the NewSite code. existingsite is essentially just an IIS website.